# Unable to start Postgresql on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

I am using Ubuntu on WSL.
I have been trying to get a postresql server to start but I can't.

When I try to start a service using 
`service postgresql start`, it gives me

`11/main (port 5432): down`

On top of that even running the psql command gives me :

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Can anyone help me with this? I've looked at a dozen SO questions and it ultimately ends at the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try out:

```
sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```